# Installed "kvm in the cable" and now mic won't work

Tags: kvm-switch

I installed a Linkskey 2-port KVM-in-the-cable w/ audio & mic for my XP box (and a second Vista box as soon as I find another power cord & network cable) and everything works fine on the XP box except the mic. I've tried messing with settings under Audio Properties but I can't even get the Sound Recorder to pick up anything. The mic worked fine before setting up the KVM. I need the mic for Skype.

I plugged the mic in directly to the XP box just to verify that it's working, and it still is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be working automatically; you may have a malfunctioning product.

I assume you've already tried swapping the inputs?  (That is, if you have the XP machine on KVM input 1, unhook all the cables and try it with KVM input 2.)

If the microphone works with KVM-2 but not KVM-1, the unit you bought has a loose connection internally.  If the microphone doesn't work with either, the unit's mic jack may not be connected properly.  **Either way, take it back to the retailer you got it from and exchange it for another one.**

If you didn't buy it new, you need the mic, *and* you have some skill with a soldering iron, crack it open and inspect the mic wiring.  If you can locate the fault it shouldn't be difficult to replace.

Comment: Returned. Now looking for something better as that was the last one of a discontinued item.

Answer (score 0):

Have/can you check the audio cable from the KVM to the computer?

Double check that everything is plugged in firmly and (in the case of the PC) to the correct socket. I know that you probably have, but it doesn't hurt to double check and eliminate the obvious.

Comment: I did check the plugs and they're fine. Also rebooted, just in case (hey, it's Windows).